# Change background image on div, based on another div's ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm struggling with this problem after a numerous attempts to make it work, so now I'm stepping forward and asking you guys for help.

The goal here is to make the `.nd-some-slide` to change its background image, by pressing some of the `.nd-some-btn` links below.

I have got to the point where it changes the background image of the slide, but it's just the `#facebook` id it seems, and no matter what link is pressed below the slide, it's always the `#facebook`...

Without any further do, here is what I've achieved so far:

HTML

```
<div id="nd-some">
<div class="nd-some-slide">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="nd-some-btn-pad">
    <div class="nd-some-btn" id="facebook">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="nd-some-btn" id="twitter">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="nd-some-btn" id="googleplus">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="nd-some-btn" id="youtube">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="nd-some-btn" id="pinterest">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="nd-some-btn" id="instagram">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="nd-some-btn" id="linkedin">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nd-some {
    height: auto;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #777;
}

.nd-some-slide {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 90px;
    background: #000;
}

.nd-some-btn-pad {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 2px solid white;
}

.nd-some-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 32px;
    min-width: 32px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.selected {
    background: #fff;
}

/* Buttons */
#facebook { background: url(http://goo.gl/rBQCg0) no-repeat; background-size: contain; }
#twitter { background: url(http://goo.gl/xmgsU9) no-repeat; background-size: contain; }
#googleplus { background: url(http://goo.gl/EGHtFf) no-repeat; background-size: contain; }
#youtube { background: url(http://goo.gl/zkM82I) no-repeat; background-size: contain; }
#pinterest { background: url(http://goo.gl/Z2Gl3A) no-repeat; background-size: contain; }
#instagram { background: url(http://goo.gl/aFqJC4) no-repeat; background-size: contain; }
#linkedin { background: url(http://goo.gl/vTet0u) no-repeat; background-size: contain; }

/* Slides */
#facebook-slide { background: url(http://goo.gl/rBQCg0) no-repeat; background-size: contain; }
#twitter-slide { background: url(http://goo.gl/xmgsU9) no-repeat; background-size: contain; }
#googleplus-slide { background: url(http://goo.gl/EGHtFf) no-repeat; background-size: contain; }
#youtube-slide { background: url(http://goo.gl/zkM82I) no-repeat; background-size: contain; }
#pinterest-slide { background: url(http://goo.gl/Z2Gl3A) no-repeat; background-size: contain; }
#instagram-slide { background: url(http://goo.gl/aFqJC4) no-repeat; background-size: contain; }
#linkedin-slide { background: url(http://goo.gl/vTet0u) no-repeat; background-size: contain; }
```

JS:

```
var network = $('.nd-some-btn').attr('id');
var slidebg = $('.nd-some-slide');

$(".nd-some-btn").click(function() {
    $(".nd-some-btn").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");

        $(slidebg).attr('id', network+'-slide');

});
```

Here is my [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ProDexorite/xqxx8pwn/13/), thanks for any help and advice!

Comment: Always post code in your question.

Comment: @Satpal Sorry for that, I thought it wouldn't be necessary with the JSFiddle included, but here you go, I've added the code to here as well!

Comment: Please first add `.nd-some-btn{border: 1px solid;}` in fiddle because otherwise buttons are hard to find out.

Comment: Updated the Fiddle with white borders around each of the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple fix in your javascript.

You want the `id` of the button that's clicked. You simply need to refactor your code like so:

```
var $slidebg = $('.nd-some-slide');
var $buttons = $('.nd-some-btn');

$buttons.click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var network = $this.attr('id');

  $buttons.removeClass('selected');
  $this.addClass('selected');

  $slidebg.attr('id', network + '-slide');
});
```

By specifying `var network = $('.nd-some-btn').attr('id');` before the click listener, you're effectively grabbing the `id` of the first element in the list of `.nd-some-btn`'s, which, in this particular case, is facebook.

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly what I was trying to achieve here! I was going to say that it's not working properly, but you managed to edit it out before that. Good job!

Comment: I don't know why, but something about changing ID of an object seems weird to me... but I'll move on from that. I'd also refoactor the CSS so you only have to change background images in one place: `#facebook, #facebook-slide { stuff }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to get network from id attr on every click to .nd-some-btn

```
$(".nd-some-btn").click(function() {
     var network = $(this).attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution.

Just use the below script in your js

```
var slidebg = $('.nd-some-slide');
$(".nd-some-btn").click(function() {
  $(".nd-some-btn").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  var network = $(this).attr('id');    
    $(slidebg).attr('id', network+'-slide');
});
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You set the variable which contains the id on start of the application instead of calling it on the function call. Therefore just move it into you function.

```
$(".nd-some-btn").click(function() {
    $(".nd-some-btn").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    var network = $(this).attr('id');
    $(slidebg).attr('id', network+'-slide');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`attr ()` method works like this - Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

So following line your code - 
`var network = $('.nd-some-btn').attr('id')` will  return the id attribute of the first matched element, and that is `#facebook`

If your objective is to get the id of the clicked element, then you can do that in the click handler like this

var network = `$(this).attr('id')`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get rid of the extra id's in your css and use the following in your jQuery. This gets the bacground image from the clicked button and applies it to your target div.

```
var network = $('.nd-some-btn').attr('id');
var slidebg = $('.nd-some-slide');

$(".nd-some-btn").click(function() {
    $(".nd-some-btn").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");

    $(slidebg).css("background-image", $(this).css("background-image"))

});
```

You may also want to add the following css to give your target div some basic background properties:

```
.nd-some-slide {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;   
}
```

This has the added bonus in that you haven't duplicated styles or code.

For more info see [jQuery .css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)